# How can I get log-likelihoods in mitools (survey design with multiple imputed datasets)?

Tags: r, survey, imputation

I've run successfully a logistic regression for a complex design survey where data were imputed in multiple datasets with mitools.
Although I can get the confidence interval and the significance of each variable, I'm interested in studying the significance of a block of variables (dummy variables that represent a categorical variable with several categories). That could be accomplished subtracting the log-likelihoods of models with and without this block of variables.

Can this be accomplished with mitools?

Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for something similar to this?  http://asdfree.com/national-health-interview-survey-nhis.html#regression-models-and-tests-of-association-26

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of code I'm using to get the coefficients, confidence intervals and p values for each variable, but I need a test to check the significance of a group of variables at once